# C# What is the Best Practices/Standards way of dealing with this specific "use of unassigned variable" issue?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Let me preface this by saying that I understand perfectly what causes "use of unassigned".  That's not the issue here.

In the following code, `attribs` is declared, but not assigned.  The compiler thinks that when it gets to `AddCalcField()`, the variable could possibly be unassigned.

```
string tables = "AllObjects,Computer,Group,Person";

for (int i = 0; i < tables.Split(',').Length; i++) {

    ADAttributes attribs; 

    switch (tables.Split(',')[i]) {
    
        case "Computer": attribs = computerAttributes; break;
        case "Group": attribs = groupAttributes; break;
        case "Person": attribs = personAttributes; break;
        case "AllObjects": attribs = allObjectAttributes; break;
        default: Environment.Exit(-5); break;
        
    }

    // Later on in the code....
    
    AddCalcField(attribs, "accountexpires", (string)rs["accountexpires"]);
    
    // ERROR: Use of unassigned variable "attribs"
    
}
```

**But it behaves this way because it cannot look at that `switch` and determine that `attribs` *absolutely, positively* will be assigned, because the program is going to drop dead on the spot if it isn't.**

The issue can be solved by simply arbitrarily picking one of the four attribute groups to be the default value.  Thus, simply doing this solves the entire problem and lets the program build without error:

```
ADAttributes attribs = computerAttributes;
```

But this seems "wrong".  I'm wasting resources assigning an unnecessary initial value which will immediately be overwritten, by the same thing.

Is there a Best Practices or some standard design pattern for handling this scenario?

**EDIT:** Or is there a way to tell the compiler to ignore this potential error and build anyway?

Comment: Unrelated fyi - you're doing a lot unnecessary splitting there!

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils.  Roger that.  I left it that way to reduce lines of code.  Ordinarily, if I was going to reference that a lot, I would assign it to a variable.  But I hate baggage variables if I can avoid them.  ;-)  Thanks for noticing.

Comment: *I'm wasting resources* - this question will forever consume more resources than that line of code. It'll probably consume more resources than every similar line of code you'll ever write

Comment: It's odd to worry about the cheap unnecessary assignment but not worry about all the extra work and potential garbage the repetitive splits cause.

Comment: *I left it that way to reduce lines of code* - you'd happily split a string twice on every pass of a loop, once just to get the count of split strings? It's no more lines of code to write `var tables = "AllObjects Computer Group Person".Split()`, but it saves generating and throwing away 8 strings on every loop

Comment: *I hate baggage variables if I can avoid them* - but C#'s already done the work to generate the data for it; caching it into a variable is trivial. The logic is like saying "I need a linux ISO 500 times a day, but to save on putting it on a USB I wait for it to download every time"

Comment: The idea was to keep the number of lines of code, in the example, to a minimum so as to focus on what was actually the issue.  The shorter the example, the easier it is to see what I am actually interested in.  ;-)  See comment I left for you in your answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put

```
default: attribs = default; Environment.Exit(-5); break;
```

or similar, that way the compiler will be happy it's definitely assigned, and you'll only burn a few nanoseconds of CPU time in the case that you add another element to the CSV in `tables` and forget to add it to the `switch` (but your program exits shortly afterwards, so it'll be fairly obvious something is awry! :) )

You have bigger resource-saving fish to fry with the incessant `Split()`ing

Comment: That would be perfect.  What is "default?"  Also, the splitting, in the actual code, I store in a variable and use that.  "string thisTable = tables.Split(',')[i];".  I just didn't want to add additional extra lines of code in the example so as to highlight what I was really focusing on.  ;-)

Comment: And I added the "attribs = default", and that did the trick.  What is "default", though.  It doesn't really matter, because whatever it is, it's never going to get used.  I'm just curious what it is.

Comment: `default` is short for "default for the type" so if it's a reference type, it's null, if it's e.g. some numeric like int or double it's 0, a DateTime it's MinValue etc. whatever value something gets if it's a class level variable that hasn't been given any value: `class X { private int y; }` (y is 0 here)

Comment: Local variables aren't like class variables; they don't get a default value if you don't give them one. If the compiler can see a local var getting used and it's not sure it's definitely assigned a value you get the error. Definite assignment isn't perfect; in your case of course the program exits before the use but the compiler isn't sophisticated enough to work that out; it just sees "switch with case where no assignment is made; may not be assigned by time of use"